# Java code issue

Tags: java

I'm having an issue with my code. It won't compile and every time I try to fix it I get an error. I can't see what the problem with it is. I may be just overlooking or looking too hard. I haven't done Java coding since 2006 until I took this class. The class doesn't go a lot into the coding and I'm trying to work off of my memory. I have been working on this code and looking at this code since I wrote it over a week ago. Can someone look and tell me what I screwed up. It's already past-due. I already showed the teacher but haven't got any help and my school doesn't currently have a tutor for this class during this semester. Please help! Code and errors are below:
Errors:

```html
/*
* File: Guitar2.java
* Author: Eppards,Michael
* Date: June 11, 2018
*/

class Guitar2 {
    private int numStrings;
    private double guitarLength;
    private Color guitarColor;
    private Manufacturer guitarManufacturer;

    enum Manufacturer {
        GIBSON,
        FENDER,
        IBANEZ;
    }

    enum Color {
        RED,
        BLUE,
        BLACK;
    }
    // Default Constructor
    private Guitar2() {
        this.numStrings = 6;
        this.guitarLength = 28.2;
        this.guitarColor = Color.RED;
        this.guitarManufacturer = Manufacturer.GIBSON;
    }

    // Argument Constructor
    private Guitar2(int numStrings, double guitarLength, Color guitarColor, Manufacturer guitarMaker) {
        this.numStrings = numStrings;
        this.guitarLength = guitarLength;
        this.guitarColor = guitarColor;
        this.guitarManufacturer = guitarMaker;
    }

    // Getters
    public int getNumStrings() {
        return numStrings;
    }

    public double getGuitarLength() {
        return guitarLength;
    }

    public Color getGuitarColor() {
        return guitarColor;
    }

    public Manufacturer getGuitarManufacturer() {
        return guitarManufacturer;
    }

    // playGuitar method for 16 randomly selected musical notes
    enum Notes {
        A(1),
        B(4),
        C(1),
        D(2),
        E(0.25),
        F(0.5),
        G(0.5);

        double duration;

        private Notes(double duration) {
            this.duration = duration;
        }
    }

    public String playGuitar() {
        String play = "[";

        int a;
        int b;
        // initiate a random number
       Random rn = new Random();
        // for loop to select random notes
        for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
            a = rn.nextInt(7);
            b = rn.nextInt(5);
            play = play + Notes.values()[a] + "(" + Notes.values()[a].duration + ")";
            if (k != 15) play = play + ",";
        }
        play = play + ']';

        return play;
    }

    // used to return the info in a string
    public String toString() {
        String infoString = "(numStrings=" + this.numStrings + ", guitarLength=" + this.guitarLength + ",guitarManufacturer=" + this.guitarManufacturer + ",guitarColor=" + (this.guitarColor == null ? "none" : this.guitarColor.name()) + ")";
        return infoString;
    }
}
```

Guitar2.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
       Random rn = new Random();
       ^
  symbol:   class Random
  location: class Guitar2
Guitar2.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
       Random rn = new Random();
                       ^
  symbol:   class Random
  location: class Guitar2
2 errors

Comment: And what is your compile error?

Comment: the errors are (at the moment I have a lot) 50,58,61,63, 65,66,67,69, 72, 74,77,78, 79, 81, 83, and 86. I have kept changing and was dumb enough to save over my old codes and not save them.

Comment: This code is filled with typos like `rturn` and `newRandom()`. Are you writing code in Notepad or something? These errors should be obvious if you're coding in a real IDE (IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, Netbeans...) which will highlight them all.

Comment: Show compile errors as they are displayed, `50` and so on are meaningless and put all these details in your question directly, not as comments.

Comment: yes the teacher wanted it in note. thank you I wasn't catching those. radiodef thank you.

Comment: I just added it Patrick maybe that can help. Radiodef I will put it in one and see what errors and then copy what I get back over. thank you to both of you. I have been looking at this for a bit as I said and looking for help. so thank you.

Comment: @MichaelEppards the specific problem immediately before line 50 is an extra closing `}`, meaning the `playGuitar` method is outside the class. You would make life easier for yourself and others if you learned to indent your code properly.

Comment: thank you I have gotten further I will update in a bit. thank you for input and help

Comment: Please edit your title to summarize the core technical issue of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-Hello, World!-

There were quite a few issues with the code that caused it to not compile. I fixed all of them (I think) and have written out what was wrong:

- `Public` needs to be changed to `public`
- The second `Guitar` constructor is missing all it's parameters.
- Enums need to be referenced by their name, you can't just type in their values.
- Your curly braces were all over the place. There were way more closing than opening, so I deleted a bunch of them at the end and ones that were tossed into the middle of the class.
- Methods must be within classes.
- Enums can't be declared inside methods, only inside classes.
- Variable declarations must have a space between the type and the name of the variable. Example: `int_a;` needs to be `int a;`
- Your `Duration` enum has no constructor that accepts and int.
- Getting a random value of an enum based on its index is done by doing `Notes.values()[a];`, not `Notes[a];`
- No idea where the `return Optional.empty();` line should be, so I deleted it.
- You're missing the import for the `Random` class.
- Strings can't be on multiple lines.
- `.orElse()` is not a method. Deleted this, unsure what it was supposed to do.
- `colorName()` is not a method. I changed it to: `(this.guitarColor == null ? "none" : this.guitarColor.name())`.
- The name of the variable in the `toString()` method is not the same as what you try to return. I changed them both to `infoString`.
- You have a TON of typos, namely with things like `Manufacturer` being `Manufacur` and `return` being `rturn`.
- When initializing a variable, you must have a space after `new`.
- Your getter methods do not return the correct type.
- The name of the variable `numString` is repeatedly referred to as `numStrings`. I added the s to the original variable declaration.

Below are a list of things you really SHOULD change, but you don't need to change.

- All enum names should be in ALL CAPS.
- Method names should be written using `camelCase`. Example: `myVal` would have a getter named `getMyVal()`.
- Have blank lines between methods, constructors, and types.
- Have a space after the start of a comment. Example: `// Comment` Bad Example: `//Comment`
- Have some sort of sorting pattern for enums. For notes, it should be alphabetical.
- There is no need to have another enum for the duration of notes. This can easily be done in the note itself.
- There is no need to do `String.valueOf(someObject)` for concatenation. It is better to do `someObject.toString()` and best to just leave it as `someObject` because the runtime will do that operation for you.
- There should be a space before and after arithmetic operators like `+` and `-`.

I would highly recommend you read up on some basic Java tutorials and look at the [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html). It is what I use and what I'm sure a lot of people use to determine how code should look.

With all the changes and with the proper use of style, your code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Random;

/*
* File: Guitar.java
* Author: Eppards,Michael
* Date: June 11, 2018
*/

class Guitar {
    private int numStrings;
    private double guitarLength;
    private Color guitarColor;
    private Manufacturer guitarManufacturer;

    enum Manufacturer {
        GIBSON,
        FENDER,
        IBANEZ;
    }

    enum Color {
        RED,
        BLUE,
        BLACK;
    }

    enum Notes {
        A(1),
        B(4),
        C(1),
        D(2),
        E(0.25),
        F(0.5),
        G(0.5);

        double duration;

        private Notes(double duration) {
            this.duration = duration;
        }
    }

    // Default Constructor
    private Guitar() {
        this.numStrings = 6;
        this.guitarLength = 28.2;
        this.guitarColor = Color.RED;
        this.guitarManufacturer = Manufacturer.GIBSON;
    }

    // Argument Constructor
    private Guitar(int numStrings, double guitarLength, Color guitarColor, Manufacturer guitarMaker) {
        this.numStrings = numStrings;
        this.guitarLength = guitarLength;
        this.guitarColor = guitarColor;
        this.guitarManufacturer = guitarMaker;
    }

    // Getters
    public int getNumStrings() {
        return numStrings;
    }

    public double getGuitarLength() {
        return guitarLength;
    }

    public Color getGuitarColor() {
        return guitarColor;
    }

    public Manufacturer getGuitarManufacturer() {
        return guitarManufacturer;
    }

    // playGuitar method for 16 randomly selected musical notes
    public String playGuitar() {
        String play = "[";

        int a;
        int b;
        // initiate a random number
        Random rn = new Random();
        // for loop to select random notes
        for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
            a = rn.nextInt(7);
            b = rn.nextInt(5);
            play = play + Notes.values()[a] + "(" + Notes.values()[a].duration + ")";
            if (k != 15) play = play + ",";
        }
        play = play + ']';

        return play;
    }

    // used to return the info in a string
    public String toString() {
        String infoString = "(numStrings=" + this.numStrings + ", guitarLength=" + this.guitarLength + ",guitarManufacturer=" + this.guitarManufacturer + ",guitarColor=" + (this.guitarColor == null ? "none" : this.guitarColor.name()) + ")";
        return infoString;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Friendly reminder that I made a LOT of changes to this code. You really should go look at the steps I took and make the changes yourself, otherwise you could get in trouble with your school for submitting work that is not your own.

Comment: this code still has errors and doesn't run and has more errors than my current. thanks for trying to help but your suggestions when applied don't fix the original code unfortunately and some of the suggestions you had I looked up and aren't required but suggestions. thank you for trying to help.

Comment: I separated things based on things that were an error and things that were suggestions. What doesn't work with the code? I didn't fully test it, but it definitely compiles just fine.

Edit: Also, it definitely has less errors than what you originally posted, unless you have made a ton of changes since then.

Comment: I know I tried both what you said and the code once I did that was when I looked it up. I still thank you and I will in a sec give you the error codes. I'm using your advice particularly on the style guide and looking up trying to still figure it out myself.

Comment: .java:42: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    private Guitar() .java:50: error: invalid method declaration; return type required    private Guitar(int numStrings, double guitarLength, Color guitarColor, Manufacturer guitarMaker) Java:100: error: class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: I re-ran your code with a minor edit and got it closer. so may edit it further. thank you. I kind of mixed

Comment: Guitar2.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
       Random rn = new Random();
       ^
  symbol:   class Random
  location: class Guitar2

Comment: to be honest it won't on mine it keeps giving me the above error

Comment: I found out why it was missing.

Comment: import java.util.Random;